# Whats wrong with my code i cant use scanf in vscode

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ab;
    
    printf("Whats 5+5:");
    
    int scanf("%d", int ab);
    
    printf("\nbla,bla,blabla,bla,blabla,bla,bla");
    
    if (ab == 10) {      
        printf("Correct anwser!!!");
    }    
    else { 
        printf("Incorrect anwser!!!");
    }
    
    //it says that the scanf isnt compatible with the declaration and excpected type
    //specifier
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int scanf("%d", int ab);` This is not a function call but a function declaration. Use `int result = scanf("%d", &ab);` instead and check return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
int scanf("%d", int ab);
```

the parameters beyond the 'format string' has to be address of where the input data is to be stored.  The function returns EOF or the number of successful input conversions.  suggest:

```
if( 1 != scanf("%d", &ab) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgot to put '&' int the scanf, which signals where your input goes. You don't have to state the 'int' part again. You just have to write:

```
scanf("%d",& ab);
```

That's it. It's just a simple distraction error.